# How to save html element text value into variable and then into cookie

Tags: php, html, cookies

Here is the element I want to save "Testing Google", it is text of the h2 class

```
<html>
<body>
<h2 class="topic-title">
<a href="http://www.google.com">Testing Google</a>
</h2>
```

Here im just trying to show the value for testing purposes, but getting error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in
>   /home/xwachvrb/public_html/brflnk.com/testovaci.php on line 53
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   DOMDocument::getElementsByClassName() in
>   /home/xwachvrb/public_html/brflnk.com/testovaci.php on line 54

After that saving it to cookie should be easy.

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByClassName('topic-title');
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

print $title;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$html = '<html>
<body>
<h2 class="topic-title">
<a href="http://www.google.com">Testing Google</a>
</h2>';
```

and load that into DOM

Answer (score 0):

**In DOMDocument class**
Searches for an element
**There are 3 method**

- getElementById
- getElementsByTagName
- getElementsByTagNameNS

  > getElementsByClassName is not defined in DOMDocument class

  ```
   <?php
   $html = '<html><body><h2 class="topic-title"><a 
   href="http://www.google.com">Testing Google</a></h2>';

   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->loadHTML($html);
   $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
   $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

   print($title);
  ```

For More Info http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php